Why can't my main.rs access a dev-dependency?
I have a crate that I publish to crates.io, and I want to add logging with the log crate.  That's a facade and requires a concrete implementation, but I don't want to force an implementation on the users of my crate.
I do, however, need a concrete implementation in order to test my library.  I chose env_logger.  I have some code in main.rs that does a simple example use of the library when you do a cargo run, but the main code that users are going to use is in lib.rs and modules it depends on.
I thought dev-dependencies was the tool for this.  My Cargo.toml has this:
[dependencies]
log = "0.4.22"

[dev-dependencies]
env_logger = "0.11.5"

And in main.rs the main() function starts like this:
fn main() {

    // initialize logging
    env_logger::builder().filter_level(log::LevelFilter::Debug).init();

If I try to run it, I get an error "failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module env_logger".  Now, if I move env_logger from "dev-dependencies" to "dependencies", it works fine.  But in that case I'm pushing the env_logger dependency on anyone who consumes my crate.  How can I use env_logger in main.rs without making it a transitive dependency for users of my crate?

[dev-dependencies] are only available for tests and examples (and a few other things). Perhaps you want to use one of those instead of main.rs.

dev-dependencies only get compiled for tests, examples, and benchmarks, that's how they don't propagate to your clients. You'll need to gate your use of env_logger behind some kind of conditional compilation.

The linked question answers it.  I hadn't heard of "examples" as a concept in Cargo.

If your primary goal here is testing, instead of having a main.rs in your library or an example, you probably want to use "integration test" binaries, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests.

I use the word "testing" loosely here; these aren't unit or integration tests, but rather are a way to try and use the library and print its output for human inspection.

Either way, I think the linked answers pretty well cover your options.
